# Copying Etrata, the Silencer, but not its name

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-multiplayer

If I copy [Etrata, the Silencer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEtrata%2c%20the%20Silencer%5d), but not its name as in the case of [Lazav, the Multifarious](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLazav%2c%20the%20Multifarious%5d); will its copied abilities work since Etrata's ability states "When Etrata deals damage" and Lazav doesn't copy Etrata's name? Or would it require the card to possess both the ability and name?

Comment: Self referential text always refers to the card, regardless of the name. Copied self referential text works the same, it refers to the copy.

Comment: Related (not duplicate): https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/35535/how-does-having-multiple-permanents-with-the-same-name-affect-those-permanents

Answer (score 7):

Its copied abilities would definitely work, even though Lazav is still named Lazav. See rule [201.4](http://media.wizards.com/2018/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020181005.txt):

> 201.4. Text that refers to the object it’s on by name means just that particular object and not any other objects with that name, regardless of any name changes caused by game effects.
>
> 201.4b If an ability of an object refers to that object by name, and an object with a different name gains that ability, each instance of the first name in the gained ability that refers to the first object by name should be treated as the second name.

Comment: In other words "*Whenever Etrata deals combat damage to a player*" and "*Etrata's owner shuffles Etrata into their library.*" are simply "friendly" ways to write "*Whenever this object deals combat damage to a player*" and "*This object's owner shuffles this object into their library.*"