# Ikora mutate game objects

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I mutate and place the mutate creature on top of a card that was tracking state will this be a new game object and forget whatever state it was tracking. For example, if I mutate and place the mutate on top of [Circu Dimir Lobotomist](https://scryfall.com/card/rav/196/circu-dimir-lobotomist?utm_source=mw_MTGWiki) will the card still remember what Circu removed from game or will this function like I flickered the card?

Also if the previous example is a new game object does top or bottom affect whether it's a new game object?

Sorry Circu is a bad example because he's human but the effect that I was looking for was on the card.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rayami Mutated has a different name](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/50757/rayami-mutated-has-a-different-name)

Comment: I don’t see how that is a duplicate at all... the linked question has nothing to do with whether or not mutate causes a creature to become a new object. It’s about abilities that use the name of the creature in the ability; not specific to mutate at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting creature is the same game object that you already had on the battlefield before; all it does is change characteristics. Similar to if someone cast a [Turn to Frog](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTurn%20to%20Frog%5d) on it.

This is the case whether you put the original creature card on top or on bottom of the new mutate card.

From the [Ikoria mechanics article](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/ikoria-lair-behemoths-mechanics-2020-04-02):

> It simply makes the creature that was already on the battlefield change characteristics. If that original creature was tapped, the new merged creature is tapped. If it had any counters on it, or Auras or Equipment attached to it, it still does.

Also in the overview video, it says

> It’s still the same creature it was; it just changed characteristics.

Comment: So this is basically like when memnarch changes something to an artifact, I only mention memnarch because is affect does not end at the end of turn? Doesn't the name change if the mutate is on top? Nevermind I just went through the mechanics article that you linked and they explicitly say that the name changes. I'm still curious if memnarchs permanent artifact change is basically the same as mutate, I'm not sure what rules govern permanent effects like memnarchs.

Comment: Yes, Memnarch changes the type of a permanent by adding the artifact type; in the same way mutate can change the type or name or color of a creature. The difference is that artifact is a card type, while mutate could only change the creature subtypes (since both the new and old cards have the creature type).

Comment: thank you for clarifying based on my example in my previous comment

Comment: Mutate could change any part of the type line, depending on the circumstances. For example, if you mutate a legendary creature on top of a non-legendary creature, it would gain the legendary supertype. Or if you mutate a non-artifact creature on top of an artifact creature, it would lose the artifact type.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Good point, I made a hasty generalization that's not accurate there.