# MTG Returning lands at upkeep

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

I have a card that says:

"At the beginning of your upkeep, sacrifice this card unless you return a land you control to its owner's hand."

If I have two of these on the battlefield, do I return one land for each or is returning one land enough to satisfy both conditions?

Comment: [Living Tsunami](https://www.mtgassist.com/cards/Zendikar/Living-Tsunami/) or something else? There's no need to be obtuse about which card it is...

Comment: When a card refers to itself by name, it refers to that specific card. /// All instances of the same triggered ability (whether found one one object or not) trigger, and thus each eventually resolves.

Comment: Related, but I don’t think it’s a duplicate because it’s also a question of satisfying requirements. https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/35535/how-does-having-multiple-permanents-with-the-same-name-affect-those-permanents

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the beginning of your upkeep:

1. Both instances of the card will put their own triggers onto the stack.
2. You can choose which order the triggers go onto the stack, not that it matters very much.
3. The stack resolves in LIFO order as always.
4. The first trigger resolves. You can choose whether to return a land to your hand or sacrifice the specific instance of the card that created that trigger.
5. The second trigger resolves. You can choose whether to return a land to your hand or sacrifice the specific instance of the card that created that trigger. This is a separate event from the first trigger resolving, so you cannot return the same land or otherwise count that because that land is already back in your hand.

tl;dr: you need to return one for each.

Comment: If you have some method of playing a land at instant speed, you could theoretically bounce one land, replay it, then bounce it again.

Comment: @nick012000 that's still two different lands (CR 400.7 as always). The fact they were both created by the same card is pretty much irrelevant here.