Can I attack with more than one Master of Cruelties?
I have two Master of Cruelties on the board, and I'm wondering: am I allowed to attack with both of them? I know that he has the rule of "Master of cruelties can only attack alone", but if he is the only one attacking can two attack at once?

Related: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/35535/how-does-having-multiple-permanents-with-the-same-name-affect-those-permanents (I don't think this is a duplicate, because it's really more about what "attack alone" means).

Only one1 Master of Cruelties can attack. When a card refers to itself by name, that means that copy of the card, and only that copy of the card. This is covered by rule 201.5 in the comprehensive rules:

201.5 Text that refers to the object it’s on by name means just that particular object and not any other objects with that name, regardless of any name changes caused by game effects.

When a card means to refer to other cards with the same name it will use wording like what is seen on Relentless Rats, though almost2 every card that has referenced cards with the same name has never included itself, either by specifically saying other like the Rats, or looking for cards in a zone other than where the first card is, like Slime Against Humanity looking for copies of itself in the graveyard and exile while it is still on the stack, or Squadron Hawk looking in the library when it is on the battlefield.


A way to get around restrictions like this was to force the creature in tapped and attacking. When it says it can only attack alone it means if you declare Master of Cruelties as an attacker, you can't declare any other attackers. But putting Master of Cruelties into play attacking with Kaalia of the Vast means it was never actually declared as an attacker, so the restriction doesn't apply.
Plague Rats counts itself when looking for cards named Plague Rats in play, and the copy of Shadowborn Apostle that has its ability activated can be one of the ones sacrificed.


Since we are talking ways to get around the restriction, let me mention Blade of Selves

@TheThirdMan Yes, anything that puts the creature, or a token copy of it in cases like Blade of Selves, in play attacking gets around this - Kaalia was just the most obvious example for Master of Cruelties since it was a one shot kill combo in EDH if they can't block.
